# Max messages allowed in a queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue, amqp

I am looking for  **Max messages allowed in a queue in RabbitMQ** I understand from some of the links that, there is no limit on this unless we specify.

Was searching for some authorized/from RabbitMQ information on this for some time, but not finding exact information other than below link.

[http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Max-messages-allowed-in-a-queue-in-RabbitMQ-td26063.html][1]

Well, for my scenario I have not specified max limit, now  I would like to know, if the max messages allowed in a queue is unlimited, then based on what? Does it depend on system attributes (memory) ? I mean Number of messages proportional to the memory?

Do we have this mentioned in any of RabbitMQ documents? 
Kindly share if anyone has got. Any answers much appreciated.

*Note:- am searching this info for worst case scenario*

Answer (score 2):

memory and hard drive space... that's where the limit sits.

Comment: Thank you @Dereck.. Do we have this anywhere mentioned in RabbitMQ documentation or any official docs? Reason - I have to mention this on one of my project design doc.

Comment: not directly, that i know of. i've seen this happen, though. had a shared host situation where another user had billions of messages, taking up all available memory and hard drive space. i think the best you'll get in the docs, is the info on persistence https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html

Comment: So can I consider that, if the consumers are slow, no messages can be stored and deliver in rabbitmq when memory is filled up with unack/diliver messages though disk is far from full?